# Vue list items not re-rendered on state change

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, vuejs2

I have some array of object, when user click button I fetch new array and display display some results.

It works fine until I fetch second array. When I fetch first array with one element and then fetch array with two elements it change (add or remove) only second element.

How I change array value:

```
fetchAsync(result){
  this.issue = result.body;
}
```

How `issues` looks like?

```
const issues = [
  {
    "id":100,
    "key":"DEMO-123",
    "summary":"Demo issue description",
    "devices":[
      {
        "id":100,
        "name":"iPhone6S",
        "browsers":[
          {
            "id":100,
            "name":"Safari",
            "displayVariants":[
              {
                "id":100,
                "issueKey":"DEMO-123",
                "state":1,
                "browserName":"safari",
                "user":"user-1",
                "landScope":false
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

and the value which was changed is `issues[].devices[].browsers[].displayVariants[].state`

How to force Vue to rerender this component when nested change appear?

---

**[ EDIT ]**

I render issues like this:

```
  <tr v-for="issue in issues">
    <td>
      <div>{{ issue.key }}</div>
      <div class="issue-description">[ {{ issue.summary }} ]</div>
    </td>
    <template v-for="d in issue.devices">
      <td v-for="browser in d.browsers">
        <!--{{ d }}-->
          <device v-for="variant in browser.displayVariants"
                  :variant="variant"
                  :browserId="browser.id"
                  :issueKey="issue.key"
                  :issueId="issue.id"
                  :deviceId="d.id"></device>
      </td>
    </template>
  </tr>
```

and `device` template

```
<template>
  <svg viewBox="0 0 30 30" class="mobileSVG" @click="changeState" :class="[state, {landscape: variant.landScope}]">
    <use xlink:href="#mobile"/>
  </svg>
</template>
```

Comment: The issue I think is with you render method, please can you paste that?
Are you using keys for each dynamic entries?

Comment: @aks I added template which render `issues`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think adding keys to your list will solve the problem:

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#key

Vue tries to make minimum changes to the DOM, and think that the first item has not changed, so it is not re-rendered. In your case you already have the `id`, using that as key should solve the issue.

Comment: I was using an idx key instead of my item.id key and had weird issue of wrong item content.. You saved my life!

Answer (score 5):

Vue cannot detect the following changes made to the array.
Here is the [documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Caveats).

> 1. When you directly set an item with the index, e.g.
>    vm.items[indexOfItem] = newValue
> 2. When you modify the length of the array, e.g. vm.items.length = newLength

`vm` refers to component instance.

To overcome the limitation 1 do:

```
Vue.set(items, indexOfItem, newValue)
```

For limitation 2:

```
items.splice(newLength)
```

So in your case you could do

```
this.$set(this.issues[0].devices[whateverIndex].browsers[anyIndex].displayVariants, indexOfVariant, valueOfVariant)
```